# Linq - Is there any difference in the queries

Tags: c#, linq

Both the linq queries gives same output, Is there any difference in the queries?
Which one do we need to use ?

IEnumerable.Where(Condition).Any();

IEnumerable.Any(Condition);

Comment: Have you looked at the IL?

Comment: They both appear to be functionally equivalent, in a roundabout way..

Comment: @DGibbs that wouldn't that compile, `Where()` expects a bool

Comment: @RufusL - if they are same, can I use any one of them? Will there be any performance difference ? Which is better to use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`someIEnumerable.Where(condition).Any()` is the same as `someIEnumerable.Any(condition)`.

Which one you **need** to use is a matter of opinion, but ReSharper and I prefer the shorter one. There is no performance difference that I'm aware of, only the readability.

I do know quite a few people prefer the readability of `someIEnumerable.Where(condition).Count()` over `someIEnumerable.Count(condition)`

Answer (score 0):

These two queries:

```
var q1 = list.Where(l => list1.Where(l1 => l1.Name.ToLower() == l.Name.ToLower()).Any()).ToList();
var q2 = list.Where(l => list1.Any(l1 => l1.Name.ToLower() == l.Name.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Are represented in IL as:

```
IL_01B2:  ldloc.1     // list
IL_01B3:  ldloc.0     // CS$<>8__locals0
IL_01B4:  ldftn       UserQuery+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__0
IL_01BA:  newobj      System.Func<UserQuery+Dev,System.Boolean>..ctor
IL_01BF:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<Dev>
IL_01C4:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<Dev>
IL_01C9:  stloc.2     // q1
IL_01CA:  ldloc.1     // list
IL_01CB:  ldloc.0     // CS$<>8__locals0
IL_01CC:  ldftn       UserQuery+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Main>b__2
IL_01D2:  newobj      System.Func<UserQuery+Dev,System.Boolean>..ctor
IL_01D7:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<Dev>
IL_01DC:  call        System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<Dev>
IL_01E1:  stloc.3     // q2
```

According to the IL there is no functional difference.  Looking at the IL should always be the first thing you check when asking: "is there any difference?".

As for whats better thats a matter of opinion.  To me, `Any()` makes more sense.

Side note: I would suggest using `string.Compare(string, string, bool)` instead of `==` here.